# How can I Broadcast Bonjour Onto Separate Subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, nas, bonjour

I have a Synology NAS and I want to broadcast the SMB server it is hosting over Bonjour.

It is hooked up to my Cable Modem over ethernet which also provides router capability.

All devices connected to my Cable modem are within 192.168.0.*

One of those devices is a WiFi Router, all devices connected to my WiFi Router receive a 192.168.1.* address (with the Wi-Fi Router itself getting a 192.168.0.4 address).

I find that if I am directly connected to my 192.168.0.* subnet, I have no trouble finding the Bonjour broadcast of the SMB service provided by my NAS.

But once on the 192.168.1.* subnet, then no such luck. This is despite the fact that I have no such trouble manually connecting to address on the 192.168.0.* subnet from a 192.168.1.* machine.

So how can I broadcast Bonjour onto the subnet used by my WIFI router so that WIFI devices can automatically discover the SMB server?

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour is usually based on mDNS, which uses link-scope multicasts with TTL=1. They cannot be forwarded through normal IP routing (even if multicast routing is enabled) – the gateway needs to run a relay app, such as *avahi-daemon* (the Linux Bonjour implementation) configured to relay advertisements. It doesn't have to run on the router, but it does have to run on a machine that's directly attached to both subnets.

Alternatively it might be possible to add static entries to "normal" DNS, which Bonjour also supports for service discovery, although that's a very rarely used feature.

(Note that only Linux and macOS actually use Bonjour to discover SMB file servers – Windows itself does not.)